# google maps using phonegap in android

Tags: android, cordova

I want to display the maps in android using phonegap. I copied the code shown in http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494764/PhoneGap-Geolocation-Sample-Application. I am using phonegap.0.9.4 and android emulator 2.2. I tested the application in android device. It is every time calling the fail method. Can any one tell me what the problem is or tell me where I can get a working application for displaying maps?

Comment: 1) The phonegap example you reference uses static maps, needing a key. Paul B's answer refers to google maps jsapi v3 (no key needed - newer, better maps api). 2) You must enable location/GPS in AVD or device to get location.

Answer (score 9):

An Android PhoneGap maps tutorial is [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4part1).

An even more fully featured open source maps app is available on the Android Market [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mds.gmapdemo).

Comment: Thank you..It is working in browser.But i am not getting map in android device.I got the map using http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494764/PhoneGap-Geolocation-Sample-Application. but i dont know how to add the functionalities like zooming and adding balloons and address dialogues to the location.Those functionalities are there in two minute tutorial but it didnt work in my device.What may be the problem.Can you please tell me

Comment: Is location/GPS enabled on your device from Settings -> Location?  If so, can you explain in more detail how far you got into the tutorial and what looks different from the screen shots?

Comment: thank you for response.yes I enabled Gps.I copied jquery.mobile javascript files and tmt4part1/src files,jquery.ui.map files into my www folder and given script tags src pointing to that particular js.i got the first screen shot as shown,but when i click on map i am not getting map..<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> this tag didn't work i think.

Comment: Here are some other things to check: Does the manifest file allow location?
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

What's on map page (blank screen, error msg, or ?)

Check DDMS after clicking on small map?

Verify GPS is working by loading maps.google.com in browser and enable location.

Add alert() here to confirm change page is happening:
        $('#map_square').click( function() { 
        $.mobile.changePage('#page-map', 'slide');
    });

Comment: yes..that application is working.when i am tapping on refresh or map some times it is asking complete this task using browser,dolphin browser one more option.when i click on browser it is opening maps.google.com through browser.