# Allow zooming Google-Maps with fingers - PhoneGap for Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps, cordova

I have an application in `PhoneGap` to `Android`, I use **Android 2.2** device and **Phone Gap 2.2.0** version ..

I want to allow the user by the **fingers** to zoom map

(on devices with more advanced versions it works!)

Why on this version is not working?

Do I need to define something to make it work?

It's my link to Google Maps in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

These are the permissions on the file Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a hardware issue. Many (older) android devices do not support multi-touch. You can't use pinch to zoom if your device doesn't support it.

Check [android: how can I verify, that device support multitouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584977/android-how-can-i-verify-that-device-support-multitouch)

Answer (score 2):

Have you got `user-scalable=yes` set in your viewport?

Comment: try 
map = new google.maps.Map({ zoom : true }); // upon initialization
map.setOptions({ zoom: true }); // or in runtime

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342705/google-maps-using-phonegap-in-android

read the comments below, do they help?

Comment: Its not my problem, I hava problem only with the zooming

Comment: the guy said he did not have zooming in the comments, and suggestion was Here are some other things to check: Does the manifest file allow location? android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION What's on map page (blank screen, error msg, or ?) Check DDMS after clicking on small map? Verify GPS is working by loading maps.google.com in browser and enable location. Add alert() here to confirm change page is happening: $('#map_square').click( function() { $.mobile.changePage('#page-map', 'slide'); });

Comment: Does the manifest file allow location?- yes What's on map page (blank screen, error msg, or ?) -I dont have problem with the map, Check DDMS after clicking on small map?- I use in device not emulator, Verify GPS is working by loading maps.google.com in browser and enable location- I do not use GPS, and i can to find my location,  $('#map_square').click( function() { $.mobile.changePage('#page-map', 'slide'); });- for what this?

Answer (score 1):

if you set attribute user-scalable=yes unsuccessfull,You could try this in Activity extend from DroidGap.

```
super.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    super.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: It will not let me run the application so .. I put it before the super.loadUrl ("file :/ / / android_asset / www / XXX.html");

Comment: super.loadUrl("file :/ / / android_asset / www / XXX.html",2000);//
super.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
 super.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); In my app, i just use this

Comment: It works! But it does zoom on all the application not on the map!

Comment: so. Set your view port ' <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
' and remove my zoom code. Try: var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

Comment: In main.xml file add a new attr: map:uiZoomControls="true"
  map:uiZoomGestures="true" Or map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(boolean enabled) ;map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

Comment: Sorry about my Attribute. It on Native code of Google map for android. And This a my map on Phonegap, Html code. :) http://www.mediafire.com/?3mr4oh3bh3gympw . Hope it could help

Comment: It's my fault. Sorry about that. It on Native code for Android not html code

Answer (score 1):

So you're emulator is running Android 2.2 (Froyo) correct? 
If so, first check to see what API installs you have in your environment. Sounds elementary but you want to check your packages and if you can Update each time you switch your API level.
(e.g. Fryo is API level 8)

[Fryo API Android 2.2](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.2.html) Also, have you tried manipulating your intent using object gestures specified for 2.2.

[ScaleGestureDectectorClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html)

Hope this helps you!